# error installing xen-api-sdk using opam : No package named xen-api-sdk found

Tags: opam, xenapp

I have been following the steps given [at this git repo](https://github.com/xapi-project/xen-api-sdk/blob/master/README.md) for getting up and running with XenAPI java program. I have successfully completed [first step](https://github.com/xapi-project/xen-api-sdk/blob/master/README.md#1-environment-setup) using `brew`.

however when I try to install `xen-api-sdk` dependency as given in [second step](https://github.com/xapi-project/xen-api-sdk/blob/master/README.md#2-install-dependencies)

```
opam depext -y xen-api-sdk
```

I get this error

```
 Detecting depexts using flags: x86_64 osx homebrew
 [ERROR] No package named xen-api-sdk found.
 [ERROR] No package named xen-api-sdk found.
 No extra OS packages requirements found.
```

Also, I have this command

```
 opam install -y --deps-only xen-api-sdk
```

I get the following error

```
[ERROR] No package named xen-api-sdk found
```

Also this package is not available at [opam repository store](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/index-date.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the intermediate step which was to install [xs-opam](https://github.com/xapi-project/xs-opam) using command  below

`opam repo add xs-opam https://github.com/xapi-project/xs-opam.git`

now  running `opam depext -y xen-api-sdk` will give you success

[image]